# I'm trying to trim or convert a DATETIME to just a date in SQL TERADATA

Tags: sql, datetime, teradata

e.g 22/09/2016 13:35:27.000000 to just output the date element?

Comment: `cast(col as date)` ???

Comment: Try Like in MS SQL:  CAST(col as date) OR CONVERT(Varchar(10), col, 103)

Comment: Try to convert using code like: CONVERT(Varchar(10), col, 121)

Answer (score 0):

The function you're looking for is TRUNC, which does exactly what you need.

http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_111A/ch07.077.129.html

Comment: Well, of course this works, but Standard SQL compliant `CAST(ts AS DATE)` is preferrable.